# Cloning jagged array is slower than multidimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to clone a multidimensional array that is ~ 100x100 in size, and every resource I find seems to indicate that using jagged-arrays should be more effecient (at least in lookup as multidimensional arrays uses a function-call).

But my problem is that I do a lot of cloning of these arrays and that seems to be much slower cloning jagged arrays (allocating new arrays in loops) than just doing multArray.Clone().

Example code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int matSize = 100;
            int iterations = 100000;
            Random r = new Random();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            double[][] jaggedMat = new double[matSize][];
            double[,] multiMat = new double[matSize, matSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < matSize; i++)
            {
                jaggedMat[i] = new double[matSize];
                for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++)
                {
                    double v = r.NextDouble();
                    jaggedMat[i][j] = v;
                    multiMat[i, j] = v;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning jagged matrix old school.");
            sw.Start();
            for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
            {
                double[][] copy = new double[matSize][];
                for(int j = 0; j <matSize; j++)
                {
                    copy[j] = new double[matSize];
                    for (int k = 0; k < matSize; k++)
                    {
                        copy[j][k] = jaggedMat[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning using LINQ");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                var clone = jaggedMat.Select(element => element.ToArray()).ToArray();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning multidimensional array.");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                var clone = multiMat.Clone() as double[,];
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Cloning took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This produces the following output on my computer:

Cloning jagged matrix old school.
Cloning took 4913ms
Cloning using LINQ
Cloning took 2283ms
Cloning multidimensional array.
Cloning took 712ms

As you can see its about ~3 times faster doing .Clone() on the same size matrix than actually allocating new jagged-arrays.

Anyone have any idea if there is a faster way of cloning jagged-arrays?

Comment: I hope you are running the tests in Release mode, and without the debugger (CTRL+F5 or directly in command line)... And I often add a `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;` at the beginning of the test, to boost the priority of the program during its run

Comment: I'll say that cloning a jagged array should be slower. Note that you could semi-clone the jagged array (clone each single row): `copy[j] = jagged[j].Clone as double[]`

Comment: Actually I didnt, running the test from the command-line produced similar results:
Cloning jagged matrix old school.
Cloning took 3801ms
Cloning using LINQ
Cloning took 1600ms
Cloning multidimensional array.
Cloning took 484ms

Comment: Using Benchmark.NET on a Core i7, I've got the following results for 10,000 iterations: OldSchool: **140.38 ms**, Linq: **151.74 ms**, Multi: **47.5 ms**.

Comment: You essentially discovered that Array.Clone() is micro-optimized inside the CLR, it can do it with a raw memcpy without bound-checks.   You can never beat it.  That works on a jagged array as well, but the blinding speed of it helps you discover the problem with Clone(), it is not a deep-copy.  You'd in general want to avoid indexing copy[j] and jaggedMat[j], they are loop-invariant.  The jitter optimizer can however figure that out by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
double[][] copy = new double[matSize][];
for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++)
{
    copy[j] = jaggedMat[j].Clone() as double[];
}
```

It will make the jagged array only 2x slower than the multidimensional array (on my machine 2450ms vs 1360ms). Simply put, creating 100 objects (the lines of the jagged array) has a cost. The GC will hate you a little :-) All these objects have to be allocated and then freed if the GC runs. This makes the jagged array cloning slower. I'll say that it is interesting that the cost is so slow (it seems that creating an array has the same cost as filling it, given that the multidimensional cloning is pure filling, while the jagged array cloning is half copying and half creating the array)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if it's still 2x slower than cloning the multidimensional array it doesnt really help me.

Comment: @taracus Your test was 3.5x... I've already reduced it :-) Sometimes you need to do compromises between speed and code maintainability. Multidimensional arrays are nearly non-supported in .NET (no LINQ, ...). I don't think you can speed it up more. The problem at this point is that you want to allocate 100 objects. There is a price for this.

Comment: I can understand that there is price for allocating 100 objects, but how come the multidimensional allocation doesnt pay the same price?

Comment: @taracus Because there is a single object. Count the number of `new` you have to use for creating a jagged array vs creating a multid array. Each `new` is an allocation

Answer (score 0):

I didn't measured the performance. But you could solve this much simpler with less code. My solutions serializes and deserialize the whole array to get a deep copy of it.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   var array = new int[100, 100];
   array [0, 1] = 57; // simple test data to validate the output.
   formatter.Serialize(ms, array );
   ms.Position = 0; // rewind the stream to deserialize it.
   var copied = formatter.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Comment: Ill try it, but just to note that you call your multidimensional array "jaggedArray" when it's not.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My solution works with any serializable object.

Comment: If anyone is interested your approach produced similar results as looping through the array. Note that I serialized a jagged-array and not a multidimensional-array though:
Cloning jagged with memorystream.
Cloning took 4839ms
Cloning using LINQ
Cloning took 2127ms
Cloning multidimensional array.
Cloning took 536ms